# wait for async method call back

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, silverlight-4.0, c#-3.0

I want to wait till calling the call back method end and continue my work after that. I tried something like:

```
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(_ =>
{
    DoWOrk(callbackmethod, inputstring);
    ctx.Post(state => { }.null);
```

but the callback didn't fire after the caling ot DOwork.

Comment: It sounds like your DoWork method is falling out of scope.

Answer (score 1):

```
var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<object>();
DoWork(() => { //wrap callback
  callbackmethod(); //call original callback
  tcs.SetResult(null); //signal task
}, inputstring);

var task = tcs.Task; //await this task or use ContinueWith
```

Comment: I use sikverkight 4 , so TaskCompletionSource r not supported any other options please

Comment: silver knight? please tell me more

Comment: May an event (`ManualResetEvent`) would fit your needs? I think there is a "Slim" version of it. Look at the MSDN docs, it is easy to use.